# Unable to locate an item with header and the button

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, webdriver, element

I am trying to find the xpath of the "New" button which seems under the menu header.
Help me find to click on this button

currently, it shows the xpath of "New" is  "//div[@class='item']//a" which is not working

Image is attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrpK8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg3Sa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an anchor tag above the `button` tag, so you can use the `href` value of it in the xpath to get the button.
Your xpath should be like:

```
//a[contains(@href,'contacts/new')]//button
```

Answer (score 0):

Image is showing anchor tag before button. If you want to handle `New button` then you can use below solution using `contains text`.

```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'New')]"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: FAILED: fillAndSaveContactInfo
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'New')]" because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'New')]"' is not a valid XPath expression.